# How to know blackberry device is rooted or not programatically

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-jde

In one of my application, I need to check whether device is rooted or not. For Android and iPhone , there are information available to check whether device is rooted or not, But I am not able to find any information for blackberry device.Kindly help me.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

That's because BlackBerry 10 cannot be rooted right now.

Answer (score 2):

Every part of a BlackBerry is locked down, from the hardware, boot process, OS, to the app containers. Interestingly, the BlackBerry checks *itself* for signs of compromise, and it won't start if this test fails. In my personal opinion, it is likely safe to skip this check in your app.

Good luck!